# Why am I not able to use $this is an opencart helper?

Tags: php, opencart

I have the following helper function in `system/helper/wholesaler.php`:

```
<?php
function is_wholesaler() {
  return $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() != 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
?>
```

I loaded the helper in `system/startup.php`

The problem is that when I try to use the function I get a fatal error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context". **Is there a way to use $this in a helper?**

One alternative option would be to send $this as an argument in `is_wholesaler()` or add the function in `library/customer.php` and call it with `$this->customer->is_wholesaler()` in my opencart template view files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an `object` for the `Customer` and you can use that `object` as an **reference** for that `class`

```
$h = new Customer();
function is_wholesaler() {
    return $h->getCustomerGroupId() != 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Or you can also create **reference** like

```
return Customer::getCustomerGroupId() != 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working... Unknown: Non-static method Customer::getCustomerGroupId() should not be called statically in

Answer (score 1):

`$this` refers to an object (class) instance, you can't use it in a individual, you can put function `is_wholesaler` into a class like:

```
class Helper{
    private $customer;

    public function __construct($customer){
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    function is_wholesaler() {
        return $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() != 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
}

$customer = new Customer(); //I suppose you have a class named Customer in library/customer.php
$helper = new Helper($customer);
$is_wholesaler = $heler->is_wholesaler();
```

or, you just modify the function is_wholesaler it self as following:

```
function is_wholesaler() {
    $customer = new Customer(); //still suppose you have a class named Customer
    return $customer->getCustomerGroupId() != 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```